# Linux / PHP server settings for Wordpress Site

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

I've recently switched to my own cloudserver and not 100% sure what's the optimal settings to run mostly Wordpress sites would be. OS I'm running is CloudLinux 6.1 x64

A few things I'm not sure about:

Run PHP as: PHP as an Apache Module or PHP as CGI

And also if I should choose to activate "SSI".

The last thing I'm not so sure about is under PHP configurations, should I select to active "register_globals".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Apache, running PHP as an Apache module has performance benefit over running PHP as CGI.

SSI is server-side includes, and is likely referring to the feature of Apache.  You do not need to enable this.

Regarding `register_globals`, absolutely do not enable this.  It is a security flaw required for backwards compatibility of some ancient (10+ year old) PHP scripts.  If this is even an option for you, your version of PHP is out of date and shouldn't be used.  `register_globals` was removed in PHP 5.4.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: Note that SSI (server side includes) is not to be confused with PHP includes using include() or require(). These will still work with SSI turned off. SSI means Apache doing includes like <!--#include file="included.html" --> but Wordpress doesn't/won't use any of these.

Comment: Thank you. A little more clear now, noticed it's still running PHP 5.3.3, getting that updated now :)

Answer (score 0):

Fairly standard would be - run as Apache module, do not activate `register_globals` unless you know what you're doing and know why you need it, SSI is optional as well.